# Need help for using davies.test in segmented package

Tags: r, piecewise

Sorry to ask such a stupid question, but I'm really confused about it!
I have a piecewise linear regression with one breakpoint and now I want to test for significant differences of slopes with `davies.test` in package `segmented`:

```
lin.mod <- lm(y~x)
segmented.mod <- segmented(lin.mod, seg.Z=~x)
```

Now which one is correct for davies test?

```
davies.test(lin.mod, seg.Z=~x)
```

or

```
davies.test(segmented.mod, seg.Z=~x)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`davies.test(lin.mod, seg.Z=~x)` is the correct one as davies.test() only accepts lm() or glm() objects as proper input. The function calculates the break points internally.

Comment: Although the answer is correct for the specific problem at hand, `davies.test` does accept a `segmented` object. From the help: _obj: a fitted model typically returned by glm or lm. Even an object returned by segmented can be set (e.g. if interest lies in testing for an additional breakpoint)._

Comment: @Gaurav Thanks for your answer. Upvoted. I don't understand nico 's answer yet.

Comment: @nico Thanks for your comment. Please write a complete answer or a complete comment as I am in need of your precious input as I have the same issue here.